# Is it possible to show and hide sub form onclick in a Zend form

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, zend-form

Just wondering whether is it possible to show and hide a subform within a zend form on either a radio check event or button onclick event. As I have a form with user field elements and now I want a sub form with password elements which will give the user the ability to optionally change their password. However I only want to show the password elements on request (ie: click a radio button 'Change Password' and the change password elements appear).

Is this possible with Zend\Form or would I need to use client side javascript to show and hide the elements?

Comment: you will definitely have to use Javascript...

Comment: Thank-you, do you how to render a sub form?

Comment: Just add it to the form. With the 'setAttrib' method you can add a style attribute to the subform and set display to 'none'. Then add an onclick handler on another form attribute to show the subform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but that kind of thing is client side so you need to use javascript in order to do it.  Personnaly, I like to use jQuery for that kind of stuff, it makes it a lot easier.  Here is an example on how you could do it.

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form {

$field = $this->createElement('select', 'myselect');
$field->setLabel('Choose to display the form or not');
$field->setMultiOptions(array('1'='Display', '2'=>'Do not display'));
$this->addElement($field);

$field = $this->createElement('text', 'optionaltext');
$field->setLabel('This is an optional field');
$this->addElement($fiel);
}
```

Now, in your layout, you should include jQuery library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

And finally, you should include another .js file (or simply embed the code in <script> tags on your page).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(function() {
  //Function triggered when changing the value in the drop down
  $('#myselect').change(function(event) {
   if($('#myselect').val() == 1) {
    //Show elements
    $('#optionaltext').show();
    //The following line shows/hides all the dd/dt wrappers as well
    $('[id*=optionaltext]).show();
   } else {
    //Hide elements
    $('#optionaltext').hide();
    //The following line shows/hides all the dd/dt wrappers as well
    $('[id*=optionaltext]).hide();
   }
  });
 });
});
```

Now please keep in mind that I haven't tested the code and I just wrote that on top of my head before I actually finished my first coffee of the day so...  it might have a few bugs.  This being said, it should be a good start for what you want to do.  Please just ask your questions here if there is something missing or if there is a bug you can't find.  Hope this helps !