# Zend Changing Select Options on a div updates a different form on div below

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a select dropdown menu on one DIV and want the user to make a selection and when that happens below a different form appears on DIV below based on the choice they selected. Want to make this without having to do a post (page refresh).

Here is my /views/scripts/postjob/index.phtml

```
<div id="post_job">
<?php echo $this->form->setAction($this->url()); ?>
</div>
<div id="display">

</div>
```

Here is the controller

```
class PostJobController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_DivForm();

    $business = new Application_Form_BusinessCardForm();
    $calendar = new Application_Form_CalendarForm();
    $brochure = new Application_Form_BrochureForm();
    $this->view->form=$form;       

}


}
```

Now here is my /forms/DivForm

```
class Application_Form_DivForm extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{

    $this->setName("Business Card");
    $this->setMethod('post');   

    $this->addElement('select','type',
        array(
        'label'        => 'Post Job (select)',
        'onchange'      => 'showForm(this.value)',
        'value0'        => 'Select',
        'multiOptions' => array(
        'value1'    => 'Business Cards',
        'value2'   => 'Calendars',
        'value3'  => 'Brochures',
    ),
)
);


}

}
```

I am sure there are more than one way to do this but trying to find something simple. Perhaps just passing back a variable to the controller from the index.phtml and then i can do an if statement and select what form to include on the view.

Comment: You will have to add JS to your code.  Here is a post that I wrote not so long ago that should help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586220/with-in-a-zend-form-is-it-possible-to-show-and-hide-sub-form-onclick/11600168#11600168 .  Try to work from that one and if you have any questions of bugs along the way, I will be more than happy to help.

Comment: I did try this one just now but the problem is that I am trying to load completely different forms and each one with totally different fields. Let's say I have 100 different forms with each 100 different fields it would be too messy to use this method. I know how to do this with AJAX script and regular PHP. Was just wondering if Zend has some type of method that could help in returning the variable selected in jquery back to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve this problem using a AJAX to post back to another controller action and then returning data back to AJAX. Still have to figure out how to submit all these subforms when they are all dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty simple to do in PHP and even easier in a ZF action, (I don't do JS yet). I do this type of thing frequently with PHP, (I hope you don't mind a refresh).

To accomplish this bit of magic in a controller action is just a simple switch:

```
public function IndexAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_DivForm();
        $form->setAction('/postjob/index');
        $this->view->form=$form;

        //put in the if->isPost() and if->isValid() as needed.
        switch ($form->getValue('type')) {
            case ('Business Cards'):
                $this->view->form2 = new Application_Form_BusinessCardForm();
                break;
            case ('Calendars'):
                $this->view->form2 = new Application_Form_CalendarForm();
                break;
             case ('Brochures'):
                $this->view->form2 = new Application_Form_BrochureForm();
                break;
            default:
                $this->view->form2 = '';
                break;
        }
    }
```

your view might be like:

```
<div id="post_job">
    <?php echo $this->form ?>
</div>
<div id="display">
    <?php if (!empty($this->form2)): ?>
    <?php echo $this->form2 ?>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Something like this just might do the trick, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for the response, just edited question. I would need to get this done without doing a post. That would really defeat the purpose of the quick loading. I am researching on how to do this with Zend but seems like no one has done it before.

Comment: of course not you can't do it in PHP without a post. You have to use javascript to avoid a refresh. The theory is the same though. You might look at the ZendX components they ship with the full version in the extras folder. ZF was also developed to work with Dojo, which is also available in the full version.

Comment: I am working on this with AJAX so it does a POST back to controller but no refresh. So far i am able to get back the value from select to controller. Do an if statement and then it won't show the forms below.